# Hibernate weird behavior using in clause inside inner query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate and I saw a weird behavior today.

The following query works fine:

```
select x.fichaCaracterizacao.id 
from FichaParecer x 
where x.departamento in :departamentos
```

However, if I use it in a inner query it throws an exception, like this:

```
select p.fichaCaracterizacao.id 
from FichaParecer p 
where 1=1 and 
p.id in (select x.fichaCaracterizacao.id 
         from FichaParecer x 
         where x.departamento in :departamentos)
```

it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 244 [select p.fichaCaracterizacao.id from br.ufscar.siga.cadastrosgerais.entity.FichaParecer p where 1=1 and p.id in (select x.fichaCaracterizacao.id from br.ufscar.siga.cadastrosgerais.entity.FichaParecer x where x.departamento in :departamentos0_, :departamentos1_, :departamentos2_)]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1348) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

This only happens when the "departamentos" collection has more than one item.

Does Hibernate support this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I'm using Hibernate 4.0.1.Final

Comment: Be wary of `IN` lists. Databases impose restrictions on the number of elements which can be in those lists. Be especially careful if you are generating the list from an SQL statement (subquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use an old version of Hibernate, which required the in clause to be written as

```
where x.departamento in (:departamentos)
```

Comment: I use the one that comes with JBoss AS 7. Which is 4.0.1.Final. Do you know if that version has this requirement?

Comment: No. The bug I thought about affected older versions. Maybe it has been solved for queries, but not for subqueries. Does the answer solve the problem, or not?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks! I tried to do this before but it was giving me another error (org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node:...). But after I cleared this problem I could fix the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a self join to avoid the nested `IN` lists:

```
SELECT p1.fichaCaracterizacao.id 
  FROM FichaParecer p1
    INNER JOIN FichaParecer p2
  WHERE p1.id = p2.fichaCaracterizacao.id 
    AND p2.departamento in :departamentos
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a simple case to show the problem. The query in the application is bigger and couldn't solve with this trick.